# Effective way of finding GCD of 2 numbers using recursive approach

Tags: c++, math, optimization

I have been recently solving a *[problem](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/hcf-recursion)* to find **GCD/HCF** of two numbers using **Recursion**. The first solution that came to my mind was something like given below.

```
long long gcd(long long a, long long  b){
   if(!(a - b) return a;
   return gcd(max(a, b) - min(a, b), min(a, b));
}
```

I saw other people's solutions and one approach was very common which was something like given below.

```
long long gcd(long long a, long long b){ 
  if(!b) return a;
  return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

What is the *difference* between the **Time Complexities** of these two programs? How can I **optimise** the former solution and how can we say that the latter solution is efficient than any other algorithm?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/what-is-most-efficient-for-gcd)?  Notably, a recursive GCD algorithm requires only tail-recursion optimization.  In other words, it's best left as an iterative algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @Wyck . Moreover, by using bitwise operators(XOR has been used in one of the snippets), are we trying to make it more efficient?

Comment: Consider the gcd of 2000000000 and 1. How many recursive calls will your code have and how many calls the other?

Comment: You should also consider the case of the gcd of 2000000000 and 0. (Or even the gcd of 1 and 0.)

Comment: Yeah, the function will be stuck in an infinite loop if any one of the arguments would be 0 and it is also making huge number of function calls if the absolute difference between the arguments is very large. Thanks @MarkDickinson for debugging this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the Time Complexities of these two programs?

If you are talking about the time complexity, then you should consider the big-O notation. The first algorithm is `O(n)` and the second one is`O(logn)`, where `n = max(a, b)`.

> How can I optimise the former solution?

In fact, the second algorithm is a straigtforord optimization of the first one. In the first solution, if the gap between `a` and `b` is huge, it takes many subtractions for `a - b` to reach the remainder `a % b`. So we can improve this part by using the integer modulo operation instead, which yields the second algorithm.